# How to hold XML file and get the fresh info from him every time i need

Tags: c#

I want to have pointer to xml file and when ever i need to read from him some info i will go directly to the place in this xml file and bring the fresh info.

How can i hold this xml ? 
I need to give the ability to change the info in this file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to detect whenever the XML file gets modified (and react by reloading it). The example on MSDN is quite instructive.

You can't really have a "pointer to xml file" as such. I suggest using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) classes for reading / writing the XML if the file is expected to be rather big, or LINQ to XML and the [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) class if its size is more likely to be moderate.

If you come across any particular implementation problems, specify them.